# Vue 3 watch newValue and oldValue always same

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have this code, and i want to track the newVal and oldVal of the ref

```
const assessmentForm = ref<IAssessmentScheduleForm>({
      formMethodId: '',
      meetingLink: '',
      meetingSchedule: '',
      testPlaceId: '',
      testPlaceType: ''
    })

    watch(() => {
      return assessmentForm
    }, (val, oldVal) => {
      console.log(val, oldVal)
    }, { deep: true })
```

but the value is always same even i put `.value` there
is my code missing something ?

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it's unknown what happens in this component. If you mutate assessmentForm, val and oldVal are equal because they refer the same object. Also it likely should be either `watch(assessmentForm` or `watch(() => {      return assessmentForm.value`

Comment: @EstusFlask thank you for the insight, i spread the object like this `return { ...assessmentForm.value }` and it works like charm